# swift 4, Set textField localizedString placeholder COLOR

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

setting the placeholder and placeholdercolor using the attributedPlaceholder as below :

```
textField.placeholder = "SOME TEXT"
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: string ,attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black.cgColor])
```

this works fine.

but when using NSLocalizedString for placeholder like this :

**NOTE: I've created the Localizable.string file**

```
textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("textKey", comment: "Some comment")
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: string ,attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black.cgColor])
```

this code always give me an error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType set]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c40a9300'
```

am I doing it right?

Comment: Do it piece by piece. Create a `var attributedString` with the value, then set the attributedPlaceHolder. Tell us which line crash exactly. Also, what is `string` in that context?

Comment: Why set both `placeholder` and `attributedPlaceholder`?

Comment: Besides the two questions from above I have another one: why `cgColor`?

Comment: @larme i've created as you asked
'var attributedString = NSLocalizedString("textKey", comment: "some comment")
 textField.setPlaceholder(placeholder: attributedString, color: UIColor.black)'

still gives me the same error

Comment: `cgColor` might create a crash in both cases as well noticed in previous comment.

Comment: actually I tried everything, with and without cgColor
** I tried setting the placeholder and placeholdercolor, and setting the attributedString without placeholder**

but still get the error
the error direct me to appDelegate -- signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
let string = NSLocalizedString("textKey", comment: "Some comment")
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: string ,attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black])
```

Using regular `UIColor` and setting only to the `attributedPlaceholder`.

Comment: Thanks man @apineda , may I ask you why it works fine without NSLocalizedString ?

Comment: when you said "without the `NSLocalizedString` " what do you mean exactly? since the code above is using NSLocalizedString

Comment: let string = "SOME TEXT"
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: string ,attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black.cgColor])
**THIS WORKS FINE**

Comment: Alright got your point now.. Weird it does as it should not work neither. With the code like the one you sent try cleaning your project and rebuild you should have the same crash.